# Intercalate function giving Non-exhaustive patterns

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to intercalate two lists like this:

```
intercalate [0, 2, 4] [1, 3, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

So I created this function:

```
intercalate (x:xs) (y:ys) = x:(y:(intercalate xs ys))
intercalate [] [] = []
```

However I always get this error:

```
 Exception: <interactive>:3:5-57: Non-exhaustive patterns in function intercalate
```

I can't understand why!

Comment: `interleave` would be a more accurate name than `intercalate`; there is an `intercalate` function in the library whose type and purpose is different

Comment: Although this advice is dangerous here, because you should follow the accepted answer, in a situation in which you really truly are certain your patterns are exhaustive, you can put at the bottom a catch-all clause that evaluates to `error` and print an error message saying where and how your assumed invariants were violated. If you can genuinely prove correctness, you can write this error message correctly. This will shut the compiler up and possibly help you debug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A hint should be enough here:

You handle the case in which both lists are empty.

You handle the case in which both lists are nonempty.

Can you think about two more cases?

Comment: And since the asker accepted this answer, I assume they learnt from it and I'm free to provide the actual answer here. The asker did not consider the case where the two lists were different sizes and thus one or the other lists is eventually empty, but not both.